# How can i hide or remove UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I want to access all the feature that provide by `UINavigationController`.In MY Application i need to remove/hide `UINavigationController` from my FirstViewController. When my FirstViewController will display then UINavigationController is not display and FirstViewController has `UITableView`. I can select row from `UITableView` and display another `UIViewController` and then display `UINavigationController` and I can go back through `UINavigationController`.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it. You need to hide the `navigationBar` of the `navigationController`. This way the `navigationController` is completely hidden but you can still access it to push and pop viewControllers.

```
self.navigationController    = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];


SomeViewController *sVC = [[[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:sVC animated:NO];
```

Comment: Srikar - yup.. your logic is work ..but in another viewController i can not see UINavigationController :(

Comment: in another view controller unhide the `NavigationBar`. get that same instance of `navigationViewContonller` & do this - `[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];`

Answer (score 0):

add this in viewDidLoad of the viewController u need to hide navigation bar

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

and in the same viewController add

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

in `- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated`

hope it helps. happy coding :)